# Is the location of Wyoming a posteriori and analytic?

Tags: kant, analytic-synthetic-divide

I answered the following question, but wasn't absolutely sure that I did so viably:

[Fallacy?: "Wyoming - It's like no place on Earth"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45004/fallacy-wyoming-its-like-no-place-on-earth/45015#45015)

Is the location of places, like Wyoming on earth, an [a posteriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori) and [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction) judgement?

Seems so to me.

1. It is a fact about the world, which we at least can work out by looking at how things are there, as I follow the map to a place that is on Earth, or we discover a place and call it Wyoming.
2. Yet, it also seems true by virtue of the meaning of the term "Wyoming".

---

3. I don't think it's necessary, but would not be overly surprised if I'm wrong. Wyoming can be renamed, anyway.

Comment: Why "analytic" ? Wyoming is a proper name, with reference but it is hard to say "meaning"... If Wyoming instead names a crater on the Moon, it will not name a "place on Earth".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA because i thought it might be "true by virtue of the meaning of the term". did you vote to close, how is this off-topic??

Comment: But how to apply the criteria "true by virtue of the meaning of the term" to a name of Place ? The only meaning "wyoming" has is to name a US state; if instead it names a Moon crater...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i'm not saying i'm sure i'm right, i'm not any kind of philosopher, it just seems likely... if you can show otherwise then please do answer! that's the question

Comment: There's an entire philosophy of language/metaphysics literature on names:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/names/  IIR Kripke's view correctly, names are rigid designators, and so "Wyoming is on Earth" might be necessary, or might be contingent a priori (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rigid-designators/#ConPri)

Comment: yes that's why i tagged it "names" @DanHicks do you think the question is too broad?

Comment: No, I think it's basically fine.  I linked to the SEPh article because I don't know the literature on names well enough to give you a substantive and confident answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kant distinguishes synthetic judgements, which extend our knowledge beyond what we already know, from analytic ones, which clarify what we already know (see the *Introduction* to the *Critique of Pure Reason*). Furthermore, *a priori* judgements are ones which are independent of experience (sensory affection by an object) and *a  posteriori* are ones which aren't. Strictly speaking, however, as Kant elaborates in the *Doctrine of Method*, analytic judgements about empirical concepts constitute mere *explications*, so they aren't strictly *a priori* (like the judgements of mathematics or logic, for example). In this sense, indeed if we explicate the concept Wyoming, which is, without doubt, empirical, this gives us a statement, that although Kant would classify as *a priori* (because it isn't an observational statement) is also partially *a posteriori* in the sense that it explicates an empirical concept whose content was acquired through experience.